# Double sequence $z_{mn}$ Converges but it doesn't imply $z_{mn}$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, proof-verification

I have noticed an interesting thing in double sequence $z_{mn}$ and I can't see why such thing happens.

*Definition:* Double sequence $z_{mn}$ is a mapping from $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

*Definition:* We say that a double sequence  $\lim_{m,n\to\infty}z_{mn}=l$ where $l$ is finite if $\forall\epsilon>0$ there exists $N(\epsilon)\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\min(m,n)>N \rightarrow |z_{mn}-l|<\epsilon$

........................

Let $z_{r\theta}$ be a change of variable from $z_{mn}$ to polar coordinate such that $m=r\cos\theta$ and $n=r\sin\theta$ and $r=\sqrt{m^2+n^2}$

**We make $r$ and $\theta$ so that $m\rightarrow \infty$ and $n\rightarrow \infty$ as $r\rightarrow \infty$**

*Definition:* $\lim_{r\to\infty} z_{r,\theta}=l$ if $\forall\epsilon>0$ there exists $N(\epsilon)\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $r>N \rightarrow |z_{r\theta}-l|<\epsilon$

........................

*Theorem:* $\lim_{r\to\infty} z_{r,\theta}=l$ $\rightarrow$ $\lim_{m,n\to\infty} z_{mn}=l$

*Proof:* Assume $\lim_{r\to\infty} z_{r,\theta}=l$. Therefore $\forall\epsilon>0$ there exists $N_1(\epsilon)\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $r>N_1 \rightarrow |z_{r\theta}-l|<\epsilon$.

**Then $\exists N_2$ such that $\{z_{mn}|min(m,n)>max(N_2,N_1)\}\subset \{z_{r\theta}|r>N_1\}$ since $m\rightarrow \infty$ and $n\rightarrow \infty$ as $r\rightarrow \infty$, therefore $|z_{mn}-l|<\epsilon$ whenever $m,n>max(N_2,N_1)$. Hence $\lim_{m,n\to\infty} z_{mn}=l$.**

---

*Theorem:* If $\lim_{r\to\infty} z_{r,\theta}=l$ then $z_{mn}$ is bounded.

$Proof$: Assume $\lim_{r\to\infty} z_{r,\theta}=l$. So there exists $N\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|z_{r\theta}-l|<1$ for every $r>N$.

Since $\{z_{mn}|\max(m,n)>N\}\subset\{z_{r\theta}|r>N\}$ hence $|z_{mn}-l|<1$ whenever $max(m,n)>N$.
Now we have
$|z_{mn}|-|l|<|z_{mn}-l|<1$ therefore $|z_{mn}|<1+l$ for every $max(m,n)>N$.

Let $M=max\{|z_{mn}||\forall m,n\le N\} $. Then clearly $|z_{mn}|\le max\{M,1+l\} \forall m,n \in \mathbb{N}$.

---

And Now, I noticed that for a double sequence $z_{mn}=\dfrac{m^2+n^2}{m^5+n}$ something is wrong. 
After I change the variable to polar coordinate, $z_{r\theta}=\dfrac{r}{r^4\cos^4\theta+\sin\theta} \rightarrow 0$ as $r\rightarrow \infty$. And So $z_{mn}$ is convergent to 0 BUT $z_{mn}$ isn't bounded!

Since $\forall E>0$ $\exists N$ such that $|z_{1n}|=|\dfrac{1+n^2}{1+n}|>E$ whenever $n>N$.

So, where did I do any of my proofs wrong?

**$m=r\cos\theta$ and $n=r\sin\theta$. If we make $r$ and $\theta$ so that $m\rightarrow \infty$ and $n\rightarrow \infty$ as $r\rightarrow \infty$. Then first theorem should hold I think...but there should be some error in the second theorem...?**

Comment: You wouldn't mean $\min (m, n)$ instead of $\max$ in your definition of limit?

Comment: Both theorems are wrong. Both proofs go astray when asserting that there exists $N$ or $N_1(\epsilon)$ **independent on $\theta$** such that blablabla.

Comment: @Arthur No. I meant $max(m,n)$ in the defimition of limit but I meant $min(m,n)$ in the second theorem.

Comment: If you use $\max\{m,n\}$, then the sequence **does not** converge to $0$. See what happens for $\theta=\frac\pi 2$, that is, when $m=0$ and you let $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @Did I meant to define $\lim_{r\to\infty} z_{r,\theta}=l$ to be independent on $\theta$

Comment: @AndreasT m and n are natural numbers excluding 0. So $\theta$ can't be $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Then take $m=1$ or whatever and let $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @AndreasT $\{z_{mn}|max(m,n)>N_1\}\subset \{z_{r\theta}|r>N_1\}$ this would still hold for all m and n satisfying $max(m,n)>N_1$

Comment: @AndreasT Maybe, I'm not understanding you. If so, could you please explain me further. Thanks :)

Comment: @AndreasT Oh, sorry, I know what you mean now. I had max and min in the other way around. I have fixed it. Please check

Comment: I think your mistake is considering $\theta$ as fixed. Indeed _the first theorem does not hold_, as the inclusion
$$
\big\{z_{mn}\,\big|\,\min(m,n) > N_1 \big\}\subset \big\{ z_{r\theta} \,\big|\, r>N_1 \big\}
$$
is false (it holds only with $\max\{m,n\}$). In fact if you are out of $B(0,r)$ then _at least_ one between $m$ and $n$ is farther than $r$ from the origin. If you adjust properly a $\sqrt 2$ constant you indeed swap the inclusion, which is the only one that can hold.

Comment: $z_{r\theta}=\dfrac{r}{r^4\cos^4\theta+\sin\theta} \rightarrow 0$ as $r\rightarrow \infty$ is true for any fixed $\theta$ applicable in your context, but still that isn't enough for $\lim_{r\to\infty} z_{r,\theta}=0$ according to your definition!

Comment: OP: One should not modify ad infinitum a question after some answers are posted. Simply put, **this is not the way the site is supposed to function**.

Answer (score 1):

**Caveat:** The text of the question now underwent so many nontrivial modifications, *after* complete answers were posted, that answers addressing previous versions, such as the one below, run the risk of being offtopic with respect to the last version. This kind of situation is so obviously dysfunctional that one could think any conscious OP would avoid it. Alas...

---

Both theorems are wrong. Both proofs go astray when asserting that there exists $N$ or $N_1(ϵ)$ **independent on θ** such that blablabla.

A counterexample is given by the sequence $(z(m,n))$ such that $z(m,n)=0$ for every $(m,n)$ with $m\ne n^2$, and $z(n^2,n)=n$ for every $n$. Then, for every $\theta$, $z_{r,\theta}=0$ for $r$ large enough hence $\lim\limits_{r\to\infty}z_{r,\theta}=0$ for every $\theta$, but $(z(m,n))_{m,n}$ is not bounded and $\lim\limits_{m,n\to\infty}z(m,n)$ does not exist.

**Edit:** The revised definition does not make the convergence when $(m,n)\to\infty$ and the convergence when $r\to\infty$ equivalent, yet. One should replace the condition that $\theta\in(0,\pi/2)$ by the condition that $\theta\in[0,\pi/2]$.

With this modification of the revised definition, $z_{r,\theta}=r/(r^4\cos^4\theta+\sin\theta)$ does NOT converge to $0$ when $r\to\infty$ since $z_{r,\pi/2}\to\infty$.

*Exercise:* Find $\theta(r)$ in $(0,\pi/2)$ such that $z_{r,\theta(r)}\to\infty$ when $r\to\infty$.

Comment: Looking at the given sequence $z_{mn}$ such that $z_{mn}=0$ for every $(m,n)$ with $m\ne n^2$, and $z_{(n^2,n)}=n$ for every $n$. This would not have limit 0 as $r\rightarrow \infty$. Since $\exists E\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall N \in \mathbb{N}$, $\exists r>N$ and $\exists \theta \in (0,\dfrac{\pi}{2})$ such that $|z_{r\theta}-l|>E$ for any finite number $l$

Comment: I have revised the definition for $\lim_{r\to\infty} z_{r,\theta}=l$ to mean $\forall \theta \in (0,\dfrac{\pi}{2})$ independently of $\theta$

Comment: Obviously, what you meant and what you actually wrote are two different things. See my Edit, which addresses the revised version of your question.

Comment: Try $z(1,n)$. $ $

Comment: Thanks! But what if we make m and n be natural numbers excluding 0. So that $\theta \in (0,\dfrac{\pi}{2})$?

Comment: Yeah, what if? Listen, I am not sure you read with a sufficient care what I wrote but I am sure that I wrote everything necessary to debunk the false claims you might have wanted to make or you might want to make in the context of this question. Thus, I suggest you take your time to read and ponder what I wrote. And if really a problem still arises, then you summon me. Deal?

Answer (score 0):

Better answers have probably been given above. Here is a layman's approach:

First theorem is wrong due to the assumption that $\{z_{m,n} |\max(m,n) > N\} \subset \{z_{m,n} | \sqrt{m^2+n^2} > N\}$ Because $\sqrt{m^2+n^2} > N$ does not  imply that the highest of them is $> N$, but the other way around (however $\min(m,n) > N \implies (\max(m,n) > N$ and $\sqrt{m^2+n^2} > N)$ and that is probably why you thought to use it in the second theorem). For any integer $N$ then $\{\min(m,n) > N\} \supset \{\max(m,n) > N \} $

**Edit:** $\{\sqrt{m^2+n^2} > N\} \cup \{\max(m,n) > N \} \neq \{\max(m,n) > N \}$; $\{\sqrt{m^2+n^2} > N\} \cap \{\max(m,n) > N \} \neq \emptyset $

**(a circle is between its inscribed square and circumscribed square)**

Informally, the double limit could be made to converge to a limit dependent only on one variable when the elements missed by this "projection" become of negligible size (measure) in comparison with the rest. Hence it is possible to have limits that depend just on $\sqrt{m^2+n^2}$. From a simplistic point of view, in Did's example, as $\sqrt{m^2+n^2} = r \to \infty$ there are many more $m \neq n^2$ than $m = n^2$.